# How to find days between two date using jdo

Tags: java, jdo

**What I have to do**

I have to find those records whose duration is more than 72 days and don't have to use raw SQL query.

**Basic Structure**

```
public class Subscription {
    String status;
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
}
```

**Changed Structure** (because of JDO limitation or my less knowledge of JDO).

```
public class Subscription {
    String status;
    Long startDate; /* Date in epoch format */
    Long endDate; /* Date in epoch format */
    /* There are some other fields which are not needed for this question*/
}


public class PerformOperation {
    public static void main() {
        long day = 1000*60*60*24;
        Query query = pm.newQuery(Subscription.class); /*where pm is PersistentManager*/
        query.setFilter("(endDate - startDate)/day >72");
        query.declareParameter("double day");
        List<Subscription> subs = query.execute(day);
    }
}
```

**Question**

I don't want to change basic structure of domain class. Is there any better way to find days between two dates using jdo.

Comment: Does your solution not work? Or do you just feel it lacks "elegance"? In my experience, you don't always get elegance with JDO (or JPA for that matter)...

Comment: If you have a Date you can easily enough make use of standard JDO startDate.getDate() to get the days of that date. You don't say what is "wrong" with your query, and no idea what is this "elegance" that dcsohl refers to; JDOQL has Java syntax, as simple as that.

Comment: @NeilStockton  getDate() Returns the day (of the month) for the date

Comment: @deepak, yes you're right. Think about how you'd do it in SQL also, since you can add custom methods to JDOQL (if using DataNucleus). Things like DAY_OF_YEAR don't give it, so likely easier to add a column to the datastore (generated by the class) if this is something you're going to need regularly.

Comment: @NeilStockton By using "DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, enddate)" method of sql we can perform operation. I was searching same thing in jdo. I think as you are suggesting i need to add some extra columns in db.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you can add a JDOQL method extension in DataNucleus like this guide http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/extensions/rdbms_sql_methods.html  so you can create a static method DateDiff that takes in 2 args, the 2 fields and returns a NumericExpression. Then you create a JDOQL query as "... WHERE DateDiff(endDate,startDate) > 72"